# If $X_n\geq 0,~X_n\rightarrow X$ ae and $E(X_n)\leq c,$ then $E(X)\leq c.$

Tags: probability-theory, means, almost-everywhere

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of positive valued rvs on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P),$ such that $(X_n)$ converges ae to a rv $X.$ If $E(X_n)\leq c<+\infty$ for all $n$, then $X$ is integrable and $E(X)\leq c.$

Some thoughts: the dominated (bounded) convergence theorem can not be applied (at least not at first glance), since the $(X_n)$ are not uniformly 
bounded by some integrable rv $Y$ (by a constant, respectively).

Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: This follows from [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).

Comment: @T.Bongers: You should make that an answer...

Comment: Definately! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As proposed by @T.Bongers, it follows by Fatou' lemma. Indeed, $X_n,~n\geq 1$ are non negative and converge ae to $X$, so by Fatou's lemma, we get $Ε(X)\leq \liminf E(X_n)$. Since $E(X_n)\leq c$ for all  $n,$ we get 
$Ε(X)\leq \liminf E(X_n)\leq c,$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

(From my comment above.)

This follows from [Fatou's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatou%27s_lemma).